# dsync backup does not back up sieve script for empty mailbox

Tags: backup, dovecot, sieve

I am trying to backup all my mailboxes to another computer. I am using the following command:

```
dsync backup -u '\*@\*' remote:vmail@backup.example.net
```

The problem is that I have lots of mail accounts that only do a redirect using sieve, for example `contact@example.net` to `support@example.net`. In case of these mailboxes the `.dovecot.sieve` file is not backed up. As soon as I allow one mail to be saved (by temporarily changing the discard; to keep; in the sieve script) `.dovecot.sieve` is also backed up at the next dsync run.

This is Dovecot 2.2.9 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS but the backup computer runs Ubuntu 16.01.1 LTS with Dovecot 2.2.22.

Comment: A [bug report on the Dovecot mailing list](http://dovecot.org/bugreport.html) seems like the better place for this question -- Dovecot missing information during replication definitely feels like a bug.

Comment: The reason I went for the question not for the bug report is because unfortunately upgrading dovecot is not an option on the source server. So I'm hoping someone already figured out a workaround.
Just in case anyone is wondering, for now I created script that creates a tar from all the .dovecot.sieve files and transfers it to the backup computer using sftp using the remote vmail account (lftp is good for this).